# Unable to push git commit, "No changes detected"

Tags: git, phpstorm

When I try to commit my project in PHPStorm's Git plugin it'll commit as shown below.  But when I'm at this screen and I click Push it'll then say "No changes detected" instead of pushing.  Am I missing a step?

[image]

Comment: Yes, notice the "initial commit after..." message in the screenshot.  That commit is selected with the changes showing on the right side.

Comment: try to check `Push current branch to alternative branch`

Comment: @pktangyue That was it, I'm not quite sure why it worked though.  Can you post this as the answer and also provide a more detailed explination/link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While using git in bash, when we want push to remote after first commit, we should use :

```
git push -u origin master
```

With this command, set a new upstream branch for a local branch, and push.

So I think, although I have not use this gui tool before, it need follow this rule.

And `Push current branch to alternative branch` seems do exactly this. Also I think this can change the upstream branch for local branch in future.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it to version control first. If you have already done that, try refreshing the folder - sometimes the status on the files does not change and it appears as if the change was not committed when in fact it was.